# Is there an easier way to do boolean conversions?

Tags: delphi, boolean, type-conversion, delphi-xe2

I have used this scenario many times in nearly all my projects, when I'm doing some sort of data conversion, when it comes to booleans, I kinda get a little lost when it comes to making it simple. This statement below sticks out like a sore thumb all over my code:

```
if BoolVal then
  StrVal:= 'True'
else
  StrVal:= 'False';
```

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to perform this evaluation? Perhaps some use of the `Case` statement I don't know about? My actual implementation is more complex than just `StrVal` but it does consist of returning two different values depending on whether it's True or False. For example, here's some real code...

```
if fsBold in Can.Font.Style then
  ConvertTo(AddSomeOtherText + 'True')
else
  ConvertTo(AddSomeOtherText + 'False');
```

That's just to emphasize on how simple I'm hoping. I'm wondering if I can do something along the lines of this:

```
ConvertTo(AddSomeOtherText + BoolToStrCase((fsBold in Can.Font.Style), 'True', 'False'));
```

I'm sure that's not a real command, but I'm looking for that type of simplicity in one single line.

Comment: Ok that wasn't really "real" code but just as an example that I hate duplicating code for each boolean evaluation.

Comment: Does your language support the ternary operator?  StrVal =: BoolVal ? 'True' : 'False'

Comment: Strangely, I see that the exact previous question on StackOverflow related to Delphi is also asking how to make a Boolean comparison simple. Different question entirely with different answers, but both of them back-to-back...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the unit `StrUtils`, there is ifthen()

```
StrVal := IfThen(BoolVal,'True','False');
```

And for this specific case you could even use:

```
StrVal := BoolToStr(BoolVal);
```

Comment: BoolToStr has moved to SysUtils in my delphi version (XE4)

Comment: Do be careful with `BoolToStr()`. Its output is `'-1'` and `'0'` when its `UseBoolStrs` parameter is false (the default), and is based on the `TrueBoolStrs` and `FalseBoolStrs` arrays when `UseBoolStrs` is true. So you may not always get `'True'` and `'False'` on all systems. `IfThen()` would be a better choice if you need predictable results.

Answer (score 25):

Ow com'on nobody ever heard of an array indexed by boolean?

```
const
  BOOL_TEXT: array[boolean] of string = ('False', 'True');
  YES_NO_TEXT: array[boolean] of string = ('No', 'Yes');
  ERROR_OR_WARNING_TEXT: array[boolean] of string = ('Warning', 'Error');
```

It is in fact what BoolToStr itself uses!

```
function BoolToStr(B: Boolean; UseBoolStrs: Boolean = False): string;
const
  cSimpleBoolStrs: array [boolean] of String = ('0', '-1');
```

Comment: @UliGerhardt: Ah, yes, think it is ugly too, but it helps in recognizing constants when reading code, so I suffer the ugliness gladly. ;-)

Comment: It's a standard code formatting rule to always capitalize constants

Answer (score 7):

For converting Boolean to string, there's [BoolToStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.BoolToStr), which has been around since at least Delphi 2007. You can use it in your last example like this:

```
TextVal := BoolToStr((fsBold in Can.Font.Style), True);
```

For going the other direction (string to Boolean), you'd have to do an actual function. Something like this should get you started:

```
function StringToBoolean(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  TempStr: string;
begin
  TempStr := UpperCase(Value);
  Result := (TempStr = 'T') or 
            (TempStr = `TRUE`) or 
            (TempStr = 'Y');
end;

BoolVal := StringToBoolean('True');     // True
BoolVal := StringToBoolean('False');    // False
BoolVal := StringToBoolean('tRuE');     // True
```

Of course, this doesn't work if there's nonsense in `Value`, but...

Comment: Thanks, but Wouter's answer actually fills in the empty gap procedure in my question perfectly, my "BoolToStrCase" is really "IfThen"

Comment: +another 1 on the edit but SO won't let me... I've built this already and it supports integers 0/1 or 0/>0 or 0/<>0 etc.

Comment: @KenWhite is TempStr just for training fingers? ;o) - ok, now it makes sense :o)

Comment: @SirRufo: Thanks for the catch. :-) Of course, I used it because of the `UpperCase`, but then mistyped it in the code. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks. I'll leave it here in case it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: ...Adding on to the fact that I built this already, I was looking for a solution built-in to Delphi so I don't have to always depend on my libraries.

Comment: @Ken. There is a bunch of TryStrToBool etc functions in SysUtils. They work from two arrays of string: `TrueBoolStrs: array of String; FalseBoolStrs: array of String;`, with defaults of `'True'` and `'False'`. They are case-insensitive as well (use AnsiSameText)

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks. I'll have to find time to look through `SysUtils` again. :-) I try to write generic answers that are compatible back to D2007 when possible, and didn't notice that this was XE2-tagged.

Comment: It is is D2007 - that's what I'm using at the moment!

Comment: The TrueBoolStrs/FalseBoolStrs are present in D2006. Maybe even earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Try either of these. Both are way faster than default versions.

```
type
 TBooleanWordType = (bwTrue, bwYes, bwOn, bwEnabled, bwSuccessful, bwOK, bwBinary);

 BooleanWord: array [Boolean, TBooleanWordType] of String =
  (
    ('False', 'No',  'Off', 'Disabled', 'Failed',     'Cancel', '0'),
    ('True',  'Yes', 'On',  'Enabled',  'Successful', 'Ok',     '1')
  );

function BoolToStr(Value: boolean; const BooleanWordType: TBooleanWordType = bwTrue): String; inline;
begin
   Result := BooleanWord[Value, BooleanWordType];
end;

function StrToBool(const S: String): Boolean; inline;
begin
  Result := False;
  case Length(S) of
    4: Result := (LowerCase(S) = 'true');
    5: Result := not (LowerCase(S) = 'false');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This would be converting a string to a boolean, but I'm doing the opposite, boolean to string.

Comment: @JerryDodge Ah let me modify my answer :) I got a solution for that aswell.

Comment: There's already more answers here than I need, I find it hard to believe there's yet another solution

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes there is and way more flexible ;)

Comment: The way the StrToBool() function is right now, you can remove the entire `5` case. When you provide 'false', it sets the result to false, but it's already false by default. Also, when you'd call StrToBool('xxxxx'), it's going to return `true`, while 'xxxx' or 'xxxxxx' would return false.

I think something like this would be better here: 
`function StrToBool(const s:string):boolean;
var b:TBooleanType;
begin for b:=low(TbooleanWordType) to high(TbooleanWordType) do if SameText(BooleanWord[true,b],s) then Exit(True); Exit(False) end;`

Comment: This answer helped me to solve an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you're into obtuse code, here's a fun way to do it (especially of it's part of a larger Format statement), but be careful if you have more arguments following (or preceding), you will have to index the argument following the boolean explicitly (told you it was obtuse):

`Format('The value of value is %*:s', [Integer(value)+1, 'False', 'True']);`

Anyone caught using this in production code should be dealt with severely!